# Why is this solution not ideal for "Rotate Array" leetcode question?

Tags: python, arrays

the question on leetcode says "Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative."
for example
"Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]"

My solution in python was:

```
def rotate(self, nums, k):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    i = 0
    while (i < k):
        nums.insert(0, nums.pop())
        i+=1
```

This does not seem to match any of the given solutions. I am curious what the time/space complexity of this would be? Is that why this is not a given solution? OR is it best to not use array functions in tech interviews?

Thanks

Comment: imagine k being 10000000000 and your solution then so bad

Comment: It's O(nk), since `nums.insert(0, x)` is O(len(nums))

Comment: What do you mean by array function ?
Concerning your code, it's really not efficient if  `k > len(nums)`

Comment: You are getting polynomial time when you do `nums.insert(0, nums.pop())` , because `list.insert` at position 0 is O(N).

Comment: So, this would be a perfectly reasonable "first solution" in an interview, btw. But then *expect* the interviewer to ask you "so, what is the complexity of your solution? Do you think it can be improved?"

Answer (score 0):

Heres on example of `cut` list in python, not sure if this is the solution you are looking for. Where you take the list at index `k` to the `length` of the list. So in this case its `3 to 6` and you take beginning of list `0 to 2` and you take the first part of the list and you add it to the end of the list by amount of `k`.

```
nums[k:length] = [4,5,6,7]
nums[0:k] = [1,2,3]`
```

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    
    length = len(nums)
    nums[:] = nums[k:length] + nums[0:k]
    print(nums)
        
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
rotate(number,3)
```

Here is a link to some other explantions.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-program-for-array-rotation-2/

Answer (score 0):

`insert` will internally copy all the consequent n-1 elements by 1 for each iteration. Hence, your code is of time complexity O(nk) as Paul said. Thus, even though it answers the question, it is too inefficient for a large array. Instead, you could use array slicing, which is of time complexity O(N).

```
def rotate_to_right(nums, k):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    d = len(nums) - k
    nums[:]=nums[d:]+nums[:d]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    k = 3
    rotate_to_right(nums, k)
    print(nums)
```

Result:

```
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, you're right. I corrected.